# Why do we allow anonimous users to edit posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So many times I have faced a review of the question/answer that contained spam. Editor was always unknown.

On others sites this is not allowed, so why are we the exception?

Can this problem be fixed by simply allowing registered users to edit answers/questions?

Comment: I assume you mean anonymous edits aren't allowed on other chess sites, as opposed to other SE network sites? If I'm not mistaken, anonymous edits are allowed throughout the SE network (and I doubt chess.SE would become an exception to that). At least such edits get caught in the review queue instead of going into effect on the site.

Comment: Then I guess this question should be posted on the SE Meta site :)

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous users are allowed to [suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) on all other stack exchange sites.  This is exceedingly unlikely to change.  The fact that you see it in the review queue is intended behavior—in fact, it's the purpose of the review queue to catch spam and other low-quality edits *before* they make it onto the actual site.  That's why we have the review queue in the first place.  If you object to having to review spam, no-one's forcing you to be a reviewer.